# Disable user altering checkbox for Treeview nodes

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a tree view control that shows to the user the duplicated images files for two images folders, so when a duplication is found the app set the checkbox beside the tree view node to true.

It works fine but I can't prevent the user from altering the checkbox node values.

So, is it possible to disable the user altering to the checkbox for the tree view nodes, also is there other alternative control for the tree view control I can use instead?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Use the BeforeCheck event, set e.Cancel = true.

Answer (score 0):

Treeview is probably not what you want anyway.

However if this is Winforms (just a guess)

```
private void tree_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
     e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Add pepper and salt to taste

---

[`TreeView.BeforeCheck` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecheck(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Occurs before the tree node check box is checked.

**Furthermore**

> Setting the TreeNode.Checked property from within the BeforeCheck or
>   AfterCheck event causes the event to be raised multiple times and can
>   result in unexpected behavior. For example, you might set the Checked
>   property in the event handler when you are recursively updating the
>   child nodes, so that the user does not have to expand and check each
>   one individually. To prevent the event from being raised multiple
>   times, add logic to your event handler that only executes your
>   recursive code if the Action property of the TreeViewEventArgs is not
>   set to TreeViewAction.Unknown.

Comment: yup its a winform, I forgot to mention that. I just tried this solution and it didnt work well.

Comment: Do u know other alternative solution for the treeview control ?